# Java Swing Component("c") Cannot be Resolved

Tags: java

I'm currently stuck on a project at the moment component("c") cannot be resolved, I know I'm getting this issue as I'm trying to grab "c" from outside the class from the repaint method but have no idea how to get around this. As far as I'm concerned if I am able to grab "c" then my whole program would. Any help will be massively appreciated. thanks!

```
package adp.cwr2122;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class SomApplication extends JFrame {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  private final JProgressBar bar = new JProgressBar();
  private final SoM som = new SoM(800,600);
  
  public SomApplication() {

    final JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    final JPanel southPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    
    final JButton cancelButton = new JButton("Cancel");
    cancelButton.addActionListener(ev -> doCancel());

    this.bar.setMaximum(5000);
    southPanel.add(this.bar);
    southPanel.add(cancelButton, BorderLayout.EAST);

    final SomComponent c = new SomComponent(this.som);
    mainPanel.add(c);
    mainPanel.add(southPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    add(mainPanel);
    pack();
    setVisible(true);

    this.som.initialise();
    c.repaint();
    
    
    final long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while(SomApplication.this.som.range() > 0) {
      SomApplication.this.som.doOne();
      SomApplication.this.bar.setValue((int)((5000 * (SomApplication.this.som.maxRange() - SomApplication.this.som.range())) / SomApplication.this.som.maxRange()));
      c.repaint();
      }
    final long elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
    System.out.println("Done " + elapsed);
 
  }

  private void doCancel() {
    System.out.println( "Cancel button pressed");
  }
  
  private static class SomComponent extends JComponent {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final SoM som;
    public SomComponent( final SoM som) {
        this.som = som;
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
          public void run(){
              queuePaint();
              System.out.println("Thread is working");
          }
      }).start();
      }
    

      public void repaint() {
          if(SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()) {
              c.repaint();
          }
          else {
              SwingUtilities.invokeLater(c.repaint);
          }
      }
    


    
    public void queuePaint() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() { 
                System.out.println("Queue Paint is being called");
                setPaint(); }
        });
    }
    
    public void setPaint() {
        System.out.println("Paint is being called");
        paintComponent(this.getGraphics());
    }
  


    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(this.som.image().getWidth(), this.som.image().getHeight());
    }
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(final Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
      g.drawImage(this.som.image(), 0, 0, this);
      repaint();
    }
    

}
  public static void launch() {
    new SomApplication();
  }

  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        new SomApplication();
    }
  });
  }
}
```

Comment: [JavaScript is not Java](http://javascriptisnotjava.com)

Answer (score 0):

As you have recognized yourself your problem is access to `c` in the `repaint()` method. You only declare `c` in the scope of the constructor of `SomApplication`, so everything outside that scope (read: outside the curly braces of the `SomApplicaton` constructor) has no idea what `c` is supposed to be, because it is not declared.

One way to resolve this is declaring `c` as a member of `SomApplication`. However you will run into an additional problem there. Your nested class is `static`, so if you declare `c` as a member of `SomApplication`, then `SomComponent` cannot be `static` in order to "see" `c`.

Having said all that there is something fishy with your code there. Because `c` **is** an instance of `SomComponent` and presumably you intend to update itself I then don't see why `c` is in `repaint()` to begin with. Your `repaint()` does not override the `JComponent#repaint` and your `c` is presumably supposed to be `this`.

It's possible I misunderstand something about your architecture, but are you sure you need the `c` at all in there? Why don't you call `repaint()` rather than `c.repaint()` in `SomComponent`?

If you took the code piece in your `SomComponent#repaint` method from some online example, take a look at whether you need that code at all. `JComponent` already comes with `repaint()`, so maybe this is just the result of a bad copy+paste. Not sure.

Comment: Might not even need to implement any kind of `repaint()` in `SomComponent` at all, jut make sure to call the already existing `JComponent#repaint` from the Swing thread.